# SSH fingerprint issue

Tags: linux, ssh

I am using a key to log in to the machines and I have over 1000 machines to login.

The issue is when I use the key to log in it's asking me for

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:kfhfhfhfuuisiinnthhthucyFJxjfDJdjdkdmcj.
ECDSA key fingerprint is MD5:bg:dd:kk:2l:84:.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

I was using the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option but then it asked for the password. Is there any way I can skip this ECDSA fingerprint and yes/no question and directly login to the machine?

Comment: sshd -V
unknown option -- V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, This is the version I am using for Open SSH and I don't see that option is working for me.

Comment: This is resolved guys Thank you so much :)